# mysql update error when I reuse pstmt.executeUpdate in eclipse jsp file

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jsp

I have a problem using mysql update in eclipse jsp file.
I just use pstmt.executeUpdate in my jsp file. that's work right.
but when I reuse pstmt.executeUpdate for updating another host's database i can't update mysql data.

when I update second executeUpdate without update's "where" query, it's work right. I can update mysql data.

but only the problem is that when i update executeUpdate with "where", I cannot update the mysql data.

case1(no problem)

use preparedStatement1, update query with 'where' -> OK

use preparedStatement2, update query without 'where' -> OK

case2(problem)

use preparedStatement1, update query with 'where' -> OK

use preparedStatement2, update query with 'where' -> update fail

(and I already test my code in mysql workbench, there is no problem first UPDATE and second UPDATE with 'where'. I have only a problem adding update with 'where' code in my eclipse.)

behind is a my code.

```
        String DB_USER = (String)session.getAttribute("id");
        String DB_PASSWORD = (String)session.getAttribute("password"); 
        String DB_HOST = "jdbc:mysql://rds01.********.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/inventory_" + DB_USER + "?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=euckr";

        Connection con;
        PreparedStatement pstmt;

        String query = "UPDATE inventory_"+DB_USER+" SET "
            + "color1_size1 = ?, color1_size2 = ?, color1_size3 = ?, color1_size4 = ?, color1_size5 = ?, color1_size6 = ?, color1_size7 = ?, color1_size8 = ? "
                        + "WHERE NAME = ? AND YEAR = ?";

    try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

            pstmt.setInt(1, color1_size1);
            pstmt.setInt(2, color1_size2);
            pstmt.setInt(3, color1_size3);
            pstmt.setInt(4, color1_size4);
            pstmt.setInt(5, color1_size5);
            pstmt.setInt(6, color1_size6);
            pstmt.setInt(7, color1_size7);
            pstmt.setInt(8, color1_size8);
            pstmt.setString(9, name);
            pstmt.setString(10, year);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();

            String query_all = "UPDATE inventory_all SET "
                    + "color1_size1 = ?, color1_size2 = ?, color1_size3 = ?, color1_size4 = ?, color1_size5 = ?, color1_size6 = ?, color1_size7 = ?, color1_size8 = ? "
                        + "WHERE NAME = ? AND YEAR = ?";

    //behind host is another host with upper host.
            DB_HOST = "jdbc:mysql://rds01.************.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/inventory_all?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=euckr";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query_all);

            pstmt.setInt(1, color1_size1);
            pstmt.setInt(2, color1_size2);
            pstmt.setInt(3, color1_size3);
            pstmt.setInt(4, color1_size4);
            pstmt.setInt(5, color1_size5);
            pstmt.setInt(6, color1_size6);
            pstmt.setInt(7, color1_size7);
            pstmt.setInt(8, color1_size8);
            pstmt.setString(9, name);
            pstmt.setString(10, year);

//------------upper code is OK, behind code is a problem ----------------
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            pstmt.close();
            con.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: so what is the error?

Comment: i can't update mysql data using second pstmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: _When I update executeUpdate with "where", I cannot update the data._ May be your `where` condition fails.

Comment: yes, [where] condition is a problem. but i think this code have no problem, because the same upper code work right. the code is perfectly same. :(

Comment: Could you show us the java console error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different PreparedStatement object for second query. Because 
a

> preparedstatement asks for the sql and immediatly compiles itself.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt1 = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
pstmt1.executeUpdate();
PreparedStatement pstmt2 = con.prepareStatement(sql2);
pstmt2.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: With a single statement can run multiple queries.

Comment: Yes, single Statement object can be used to execute multiple queries.

Comment: Then, Is it needed to create one more object @Deepika Rajani

Comment: Statement and PreparedStatement are two different interfaces. PreparedStatement precompiles the query whereas in Statement the query is not pre-compile. So if we are using same PreparedStatement object for multiple queries, it refers to the first query(compiled) which is not the case with Statement instance. Hence, we can use same Statement for multiple queries but not PreparedStatement.

Comment: [java prepared statement multiple queries](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=GOSlVrjvHKPv8wfViLjADA&gws_rd=ssl#q=java%20prepared%20statement%20multiple%20queries) @Deepika Rajani

Comment: @Satya which link is you pointing to. I have already gone through some of them.

Comment: You no need to go through any link. Just I'm misleading you. What you told is correct. :) @Deepika Rajani

Comment: hmmmmmmmm. i'm follow different preparedStatement. but I can't update now.
case1
use preparedStatement1, update query with 'where' -> OK
use preparedStatement2, update query without 'where' -> OK

case2
use preparedStatement1, update query with 'where' -> OK
use preparedStatement2, update query with 'where' -> update fail

maybe the problem is 'where'. but i'm not solve this for 2 days. :(

Answer (score 0):

oh, I know the problem. I add the mysql privilege only update, delete, insert not select in database id.
as I add the 'select' privilege to my id, I can update in my database.
thank for all answer!